# ASP.NET MVC passing string to JSON.parse with quote escaping issue

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I hit a problem with JSON.
I want to pass serialized object to a JSON.parse method in JS.
Everything works fine until one of string values does not have quotes, like for example HTML code. Then you get JSON parse error in JS.

Simply I get:

```
var test = JSON.parse('{"test":"<p>Terms <a href=\"google.pl\"></a></p>"}');
```

But what works is:

```
var test = JSON.parse('{"test":"<p>Terms <a href=\\"google.pl\\"></a></p>"}');
```

Here is my test view code, any thoughts?
How to pass this object properly?

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@{
    string args = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        test = @"<p>Terms <a href=""google.pl""></a></p>"
    }, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
    });
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var test = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(args)');
    </script>
    <div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the actual question? Also i think it should be `var test = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(args).ToString());` instead of `var test = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(args)');`...

Comment: Nope. ToString breaks it even more as it HTML encodes it. Question is how to pass this object to successfully deserialize on JS side.

Comment: Your example is incomplete, some view code is missing.

Comment: This is the whole razor view code. What is missing?

Comment: @mzdieg I didn't understand the question, i thought something with `test` is the issue. Nevermind...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to parse it, as it is already a JSON object.
Just use:

```
<script>
    var test = @Html.Raw(args);
</script>
```

`JSON.parse` is used to parse string to object.